# Initializing two leaflet maps - one rewrites another

Tags: javascript, html, dictionary, leaflet

I'm trying to put multiple leaflet maps on one page, but I have problem with two of them - the second one rewrites the first one, so first one is rendering map, and the second has just grey area.

Here is the code:

```
var map_a = new L.Map( "smallMap", {
            fullscreenControl: false,
            layers: [osmMap]
        }).setView([51.005, -0.09], 14);

var map_b = new L.Map( "smallMapSecond", {
             fullscreenControl: false,
             layers: [osmMap]
        }).setView([51.505, -0.09], 14);
```

I have appropriate divs called smallMap and smallMapSecond. When I Initialize only one map, it works. Where could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Well,one of the potential problems I see here without having a jsFiddle available is that you are using the same tileLayer `osmMap` for both maps. Sharing TileLayers between map instances is going to cause problems. Initialize `tileLayers` one per map.